# Running both Django and PHP on IIS (Internet Information Services) server

Tags: php, django, iis, server, production

I have a previous application done with PHP and I have created another django project. I'm trying to run them both on IIS server as the existing PHP project is served through IIS. When I'm running PHP and Django separately, its working fine but if I configure IIS for running django and then go to the url of the php file (localhost/test.php), its testing for the route in urls.py and returning the possible urls like /home, /about (Django - 404 - Not Found Error). I need to display django views while visiting URLs in the urls.py and run php file while visiting the php url. Is there any way that I can do this?

Any answer is appreciable. Thanks in Advance :)

Update:
I'm able to run both PHP and Django projects and files on Apache HTTP Server(XAMPP) with installing mod_wsgi and the following configuration in the httpd.conf file.

```
LoadFile "c:/users/user_name/appdata/local/programs/python/python39/python39.dll"
LoadModule wsgi_module "c:/users/user_name/appdata/local/programs/python/python39/lib/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi.cp39-win_amd64.pyd"
WSGIPythonHome "c:/users/user_name/appdata/local/programs/python/python39"

Alias /php "c:/xampp/htdocs"

WSGIScriptAlias / "c:/users/user_name/Desktop/sample/sample/wsgi.py"
WSGIPythonPath "c:/users/user_name/Desktop/sample"

<Directory "c:/users/user_name/Desktop/sample" >
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Allow from all
        Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>
```

Comment: I am not very familiar with the content of php, but you seem to want to display the django views and run the php file by specific url. If this is the case, you can try [url rewrite](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module).

Comment: Thank you so much Samwu. I'll try this and let you know if it worked on IIS. By the way, I'm able to run in Apache HTTP server (Xampp) with mod_wsgi module and also by including an alias for the php file. I have edited the post with the code about running on Apache server.

Comment: Bad luck Samwu. Its not working. Still throws django 404 error. Its mentioned that we need to check if the URL is working normally and then rewrite to any URL that you like. Anyways thanks for the help ! still trying :(